# IntelliJ Python plugin + Win7 x64 + Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, anaconda

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 with the Python plugin on Win7 x64. As a project SDK, I selected the python.exe from the Python 3.4 x64 distribution.

Program execution works fine, however, build-in Python functions are not recognized and code completion does not work either.

I also tried it with Python 3.4 x32 and with the Python distributions WinPython 3.4.3 and Anaconda 3 instead - same problem.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Now I also tried it out with Python 2.7 - and this works fine. So in some way, the IntelliJ Python plugin seems to have a problem with Python 3 :(